# Google Earth Engine - USGS Landsat 8 Level 2, Collection 2, Tier 1 metadata, should it differ from USGS guide?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, usgs, documentation

I have been using "USGS Landsat 8 Level 2, Collection 2, Tier 1" and it's 'ST_ARAN' band and getting unexpected results.

On the GEE docs (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2?hl=en#bands) it has the scale as 1e-05.

Eventually, I noticed on the USGS product guide (https://www.usgs.gov/media/files/landsat-8-collection-2-level-2-science-product-guide) that it has the scale as 1e-04. Which, if used,  returns the results I was expecting.

Is this an area where the GEE dataset differs from a USGS direct download for some reason or is it more simply just an error in the GEE docs? Or how could I find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a documentation error in GEE. Will fix.